# mousePressed inside Constructor Function in JavaScript - p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am currently working on a Constructor Function in JavaScript - p5.js. My problem is that the `mousePressed()` function doesn't execute the code in it when I am clicking in on the right spot on the canvas. Basically what I want is that a faction of the content in the cup disappears when I click the mouse on the cup. and when I hit the button I want to fill the cup as originally filled.

Here is my file:

```
var bierglas;
var füllung;

var xPos = 200;
var yPos = 100;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(650, 450);
  bierglas = new Cup();
  füllung = new Content();
}

function draw() {
  background(51);
  füllung.show();
  füllung.button();
  füllung.move();
  bierglas.square();
  bierglas.henkel();
}

//
// This draws my cup
//
function Cup() {
  this.x = xPos;
  this.y = yPos;
  this.width = 150;
  this.height = 300;

  this.square = function() {
    fill(255, 150);
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  };
  this.henkel = function() {
    arc(this.x + this.width, this.y + this.height / 2, 150, 120, 0, HALF_PI);
    arc(this.x + this.width, this.y + this.height / 2, 150, 120, 0, 0);
  };
}

//
// This is for the mousePressed function, the content of the cup and the button
//
function Content() {
  this.x = xPos;
  this.y = yPos;
  this.width = 150;
  this.height = 300;

  this.buttonX = width - width / 4;
  this.buttonY = height - height / 6;
  this.buttonWidth = width / 8;
  this.buttonHeight = height / 6;

  this.show = function() {
    fill(0, 200, 200);
    rect(this.x, this.y * 2, this.width, this.height - this.y);
  };

  this.button = function() {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(this.buttonX, this.buttonY, this.buttonWidth, this.buttonHeight);
  };

  this.move = function() {
    mousePressed();
  };
}

function mousePressed() {
  if (
    mouseX < this.x + this.width &&
    mouseX > this.x &&
    mouseY < this.y + (this.height - this.y) &&
    mouseY > this.y
  ) {
    this.y * 2;
    console.log("Auf Bierglas getippt");
  }
  if (
    mouseX > this.buttonX &&
    mouseX < this.buttonX + this.buttonWidth &&
    mouseY > this.buttonY &&
    mouseY < this.buttonY + this.buttonHeight
  ) {
    this.y = yPos;
    console.log("Auf Button getippt");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get into the habit of checking the [developer console](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) for errors. You'll see that your `mousePressed()` function is indeed firing, but it's hitting an error.

Let's look at the first few lines of your `mousePressed()` function:

```
function mousePressed() {
  if (
    mouseX < this.x + this.width &&
    mouseX > this.x &&
    mouseY < this.y + (this.height - this.y) &&
    mouseY > this.y
  ) {
    this.y * 2;
```

You have a few problems here. What do you think `this` is? I'm guessing that you thought it was an instance of `Content`, but this is not the case. Therefore, `this` does not contain variables like `x`, `y`, `width`, or `height`, which is why you're getting your errors. Also, notice that `this.y * 2` doesn't actually do anything with the resulting value.

If I were you, I would [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and take those steps on one at a time. Try to get a very simple sketch that uses `mousePressed()` working:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
}

function mousePressed(){
    console.log("mouse pressed");
}
```

Next, try to create a simple sketch that contains one object with a function that you call from the sketch-level `mousePressed()` function. Here's an example:

```
var myObject = new MyObject();

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
}

function mousePressed(){
    myObject.mousePressed();
}

function MyObject(){
    this.mousePressed = function(){
        console.log("object mouse pressed");
    };
}
```

Work your way forward in small steps like this, and remember to always check the developer console for errors. Good luck.